# iOS Pinch Zoom - Can't disable with viewport now

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have been using the meta tag for viewport, like Apple says on their own developer page, now for years on my responsive designs. As of recently my iPhone is now able to zoom in even with the following

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width;" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
```

The initial page loads to the correct size, but the users can now zoom in closer and the viewport isn't working. I was wondering if there is a way to disable to pinch to zoom using jQuery? Since I am already using some on my page it would be easy to implement.

**Please note**: Even on other websites like `davidwalsh.name/demo/mobile-viewport.php` that used to work it can now zoom in. I imagine this is part of the change with html5 released in December that disallows the maximum-scale attribute in meta tags but I cannot be sure. I have been using noBounce.js on page up until now that disabled all the iOS bounce and zoom capabilities but I am not sure which part is controling the zoom to steal that bit out of it and I don't use noBounce anymore on most apps for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 10, the mobile Safari browser will ignore `user-scalable=no` and will allow pinch and zoom on every website to improve accessibility.

From the iOS 10 changelog:

> To improve the accessibility on websites in Safari, users can now pinch-to-zoom even when a website sets user-scalable=no in the viewport.

It looks like we will have to start designing sites with pinch and zoom in mind, at least for Apple devices.

Comment: Seems like a terrible decision on Apples part since the website is already designed for mobile in most cases. Not sure how I am going to handle zooming the page to 200% since it doesn't readjust on resize, rather the browser just zooms in on content without changing display.

Answer (score 0):

I came up on the iOS10 Pinch-to-Zoom problem, i could fix this issue with a manipulation inside of the head-tag to the PortableWebApp(Cordova).

What i did was just to add this line in my init() from app.js

```
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width;" />');
```

The App is now Scrollable, adapts to different screen sizes/devices and no more Pinch-to-Zoom.
Note: remember this only works for Hybrid Apps, Safari is not affected by this workaround.